# Randomized Testing in java- what is it and how to achieve it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, random, junit

I was confused about Randomized testing. 
It is cited form proj1b spec:

> "The autograder project 1A largely relies on *randomized tests.* For
>   example, our JUnit tests on gradescope simply call random methods of
>   your LinkedListDeque class and our correct implementation
>   LinkedListDequeSolution and as soon as we see any disagreement, the
>   test fails and prints out a sequence of operations that caused the
>   failure. "

(http://datastructur.es/sp17/materials/proj/proj1b/proj1b.html)

I do not understand what it means by:

> "call random methods of the tested class and the correct class"

I need to write something really similar with that autograder. But I do not know if I need to write tests for different methods together by using a loop to random pick up some to test?

If so, we can test all methods by using JUnit, why we need to randomized test?

Also, if I combine all the tests together, why I call it JUnit?

If you do not mind, some examples will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the "random" testing.

There is a framework called [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck), initially written for the Haskell programming language. But it has been ported to many other languages - also for Java. There is [jqwik](http://jqwik.net/) for junit5, or (probably outdated) [jcheck](http://www.jcheck.org/).

The idea is "simply":

- you describe *properties* of your methods, like (a(b(x)) == b(a(x))
- the framework then created **random** input for method calls, and tries to find examples where a property doesn't hold

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are talking about Model Based Testing. For that you'd have to create models - simplified versions of your production behaviour. Then you can list possible methods that can be invoked and the dependencies between those methods. After that you'd have to choose a random one and invoke both - method of your model and the method of your app. If the results are the same, then it works right. If the results differ - either there is a bug in your model or in your app. You can read more [in this article](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html).

In Java you can either write this logic on your own, or use existing frameworks. The only existing one that I know in Java is [GraphWalker](http://graphwalker.github.io/). But I haven't used it and don't know how good it is.

The original frameworks (like QuichCheck) are also able to "shrink" - if it took 50 calls to random methods to find a bug, then they will try to find the exact sequence of several steps that would lead to that bug. I don't know if there are such possibilities in Java frameworks, but it may be worth looking into [ScalaCheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/) if you need a JVM (but not necessarily a Java solution).